# Reset Function in Visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

Finally I made a game using Visual C# ... (With Help Of Stackoverflow members ,,, Thanx).

I Have three more questions.

1- How can I add a reset function to the application form I mean I want it to reload it self when I press a botton ( Try Again ) or somthin similler.

2- How I can add a fireworks to my application as the one in spidersolitaire when the player win.

3- how to build my Visual C# code to .exe file.

Thanx in advance

Comment: You should break this into 3 questions, and show what you have done so far if you want more help.

Comment: its a normal Application form built by visual C#

Comment: What is being built at the moment if it is not an executable?

Comment: Oh CMP just Explain this point ,,, Question No.3 is solved

Comment: @Nader If it is solved why did not you mark the solution up?

Comment: @mfeingold still two questions left Im trying hard to sove them thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In visual studio when you build and run, it puts an executable into a folder. By default this will be projects\myprojectname\bin\Debug.

If you want to let the compiler put in a few more optimizations for you so it runs slightly better, change the build configuration to Release mode, and build it. Your exe will then be in \bin\Release or something like that.

Comment: thanx that answered question No. 3